# Facebook Like Button on a web page produces an image not associated with the web page

Tags: image, facebook, button, facebook-like

I set up the index page of my new website with a Facebook like button. Everything functions properly, except that the instead of the image (the only image invoked on the web page) that I specified with - `meta property="og:image" content=` - a completely unknown image is used. It the image is of a narrow horizontal bar with some white letters.

Comment: Ok. So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

See if Facebook can tell you what's wrong via their [lint tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Cheers